# Koa-router ignores async/await of Mongoose and return 404 always

Tags: node.js, mongoose, koa, koa2, koa-router

This is the code of route. When I use commented `Promise`, it returns 123 in body. But with mongoose query it returns 404 status. Item in log founds good. But it seems router just ignore await and return 404 immediately. What am I doing wrong?

```
router.get('/:id', async (ctx, next) => {
    // var item = await Promise.resolve(123); // this line works good!
    var item = await Model.findById(ctx.params.id); // but this not
    ctx.body = item;
    console.log('hmm', item, ctx.response);
});
```

In console.log output everything good, but throws `404 Not Found` like default koa response:

```
hmm { _id: 5accda0700c0afd3ca50bc67,
  name: 'yuki 2',
  server: 5accd5848ae2e2d2be1760c6,
  owner: 5accd023cc3a90d1f73d4afd,
  createdAt: 2018-04-10T15:36:39.965Z,
  updatedAt: 2018-04-10T15:36:39.965Z,
  __v: 0 } 
 { status: 404,
  message: 'Not Found',
  header: 
   { 'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
     'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
     'content-length': '9' },
  body: { _id: 5accda0700c0afd3ca50bc67,
     name: 'yuki 2',
     server: 5accd5848ae2e2d2be1760c6,
     owner: 5accd023cc3a90d1f73d4afd,
     createdAt: 2018-04-10T15:36:39.965Z,
     updatedAt: 2018-04-10T15:36:39.965Z,
     __v: 0 } }
```

Comment: Hi. were you ever able to fix this issue? I'm experiencing the same.

Comment: Sorry, this is my bad into middleware above this code. So, question is incorrect :(

Answer (score -1):

It may be because of mongoose promise being deprecated, after the line where you require mongoose library, eg:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

You can add one line

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

or

```
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

If you are using bluebird in your project.

Comment: Nope, I'm using native promise, but it was a problem in middleware above this code.

Comment: Ok. Maybe you should add it to the question so that others can avoid such mistake!